# MongoDB PHP driver loaded but class can't be found

Tags: php, mongodb, nginx, pear

I'm trying to set up a PHP 7.1.6.1 installation with the [Mongo driver for PHP. (v1.2.9)](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/releases) However the `Mongo` class isn't loaded although `phpinfo()` tells me that the mongo extension is loaded.

Here's what I've done:

```
pecl install mongodb
echo 'extension=mongodb.so' > /etc/php/7.1/fpm/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini
serivce php7.1-fpm restart
service nginx restart
```

This installs the MongoDB PHP extension, loads it and then restarts both FPM and Nginx. When I run `php -i | grep mongo` I get the following output:

```
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini,
mongodb
libmongoc bundled version => 1.5.5
libmongoc SSL => enabled
libmongoc SSL library => OpenSSL
libmongoc crypto => enabled
libmongoc crypto library => libcrypto
libmongoc crypto system profile => disabled
libmongoc SASL => disabled
mongodb.debug => no value => no value
```

Here's a screenshot of `phpinfo()`:
[image: phpinfo() output on HTML page]

To me this looks like the MongoDB driver is loaded as it should, but my scripts complain that they can't find the `Mongo` class. I've created a small script to show the issue:

```
<?php
    if(class_exists('Mongo') || class_exists('MongoClient')) {
        echo "EUREKA!";
    } else {
        echo "Still not loading...";
}
?>
```

When running the script it returns `Still not loading...`. I've run out of ideas, is there anyone that could guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver says:

> Please note that the new HHVM and PHP drivers implement a different API from the legacy driver at http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo; therefore existing libraries that use the legacy driver (e.g. Doctrine MongoDB's ODM) will not work with the new drivers.

The list of classes is at http://docs.php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php - "Mongo" and "MongoClient" are not among them.

Comment: That was it, must've overlooked that in the documentation. Thanks!